# Oracle: CREATE TABLE AS SELECT * FROM - Column Widths Are 3X the Size

Tags: sql, oracle

Our data warehouse is AL32UTF8 and we're doing a "create table as select * from" from a hosted database that is WE8MSWIN1251.

For some reason it'll create a CHAR or a VARCHAR2 on the data warehouse 3x the size of the source database.

For instance:

ABS_ID                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10) (source)
vs
ABS_ID                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30) (dw)

The DW has NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=CHAR.

I realise it's the character set change but why won't it create as 10 characters, instead if the original is a 1-byte character set?

Unfortunately, the credentials we have don't allow us to do expdp/impdp.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Have tried changing NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS to CHAR and BYTES. Neither help.

Comment: Hi what are the Oracle version in the Source and target ? Also is it changing for all the Varchar columns or only for some ?

Comment: Because it may require more than 10 bytes in the new wider characterset

Answer (score 2):

When you pull from `WE8MSWIN1251` to `AL32UTF8`, Oracle will has to allow for a greater number of bytes to store those characters than they used in the source database. A single character using one byte in the source may require 2 or 3 bytes in the target.

If the source table uses *byte* semantics, CTAS will create the corresponding columns also with *byte* semantics, regardless of the `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` parameter. That parameter is only used when defining a new table with DDL and specifying a size without also specifying the semantics. A CTAS is an automatic column-for-column translation and will keep the size *and* semantics of the source.

When the source uses *byte* semantics, the target will also, but it has to size it up - `DATA_LENGTH` (and hence also `CHAR_LENGTH` since we're using byte semantics) will be set to **3x** the number of bytes, presumably because no character possible in the single-byte `WE8MSWIN1251` characterset would require all 4 bytes in `AL32UTF8`, but they *could* require 2 or 3.

When the source uses *char* semantics, however, the target will likewise use char semantics, and **then it will keep the # of chars (`CHAR_LENGTH`) the same**, but because `AL32UTF8` is a 4-byte characterset, the # of *bytes* (`DATA_LENGTH`) will be 4x greater.

So, if you want to see `CHAR_LENGTH` stay the same on the target, you'll need to redefine the columns in your *source* table to use `CHAR` semantics. Then CTAS will work as you expect. Alternatively, you could cast the columns yourself:

```
create table mytable as 
select col1,col2,cast(ABS_ID as varchar2(10 char)) ABS_ID 
from remotable@remotelink
```

Comment: "If the source table uses byte semantics, CTAS will create the corresponding columns also with byte semantics, regardless of the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter" - That makes sense. Theirs is using CHAR. However, you mentioned about is you said WE8MSWIN1251 is a 4-byte character set, did you mean AL32UTF is? It looks like we'll have to accept the differences or use CAST.

Comment: @Orac, yes thank you, copy-paste error, fixed. If your source is using CHAR, then you should have the same CHAR_LENGTH in the target as the source has.

Comment: @Orac, you mean your source database nls_length_semantics is char? Again, the parameter isn't what matters. It's what was used when the source table was created. Look at `all_tab_columns.char_used` in the source database for your source table. Does it say B or C ? I'm betting it says B.

Comment: You were right. It does say B. Thanks!